# Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a website with different sections. I am using segment.io to track different actions on the page. How can I detect if a user has scrolled to the bottom of a div? I have tried the following but it seems to be triggered as soon as I scroll on the page and not when 
 I reached the bottom of the div.

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
}

trackScrolling = () => {
  const wrappedElement = document.getElementById('header');
  if (wrappedElement.scrollHeight - wrappedElement.scrollTop === wrappedElement.clientHeight) {
    console.log('header bottom reached');
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
  }
};
```

Comment: This answer was helpful in detecting scroll to the bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53158893/4265546

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can use `el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom` to check if the bottom has been viewed

```
isBottom(el) {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight;
}

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
}

trackScrolling = () => {
  const wrappedElement = document.getElementById('header');
  if (this.isBottom(wrappedElement)) {
    console.log('header bottom reached');
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.trackScrolling);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's also a good practice to remove the event (`document.removeEventListener`) on component unmount (`componentWillUnmount`)

Comment: `wrappedElement` is null. Why?

Comment: @StavAlfi because you don't have a 'header' id probably

Answer (score 182):

An even simpler way to do it is with [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop), and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight).

Subtract the scrolled height from the total scrollable height. If this is equal to the visible area, you've reached the bottom!

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

(Or, to account for complications such as zoom, use the alternative formula suggested in the comments:)

```
Math.abs(element.scrollHeight - (element.scrollTop + element.clientHeight)) <= 1
```

In react, just add an onScroll listener to the scrollable element, and use `event.target` in the callback.

```
class Scrollable extends Component {

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    const bottom = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight;
    if (bottom) { ... }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollableElement onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
        <OverflowingContent />
      </ScrollableElement>
    );
  }
}
```

I found this to be more intuitive because it deals with the scrollable element itself, not the `window`, and it follows the normal React way of doing things (not using ids, ignoring DOM nodes).

You can also manipulate the equation to trigger higher up the page (lazy loading content/infinite scroll, for example).

Comment: From the `scrollTop` web doc: 
`On systems using display scaling, scrollTop may give you a decimal value.` 

If you want to account for varying levels of zoom in a browser window you might want to get the ceiling of scrollTop to compare these values. 


`node.scrollHeight - Math.ceil(node.scrollTop) === node.clientHeight`

Comment: For some reason my `scrollTop` comes out in "low" decimal values. Like 34.22233 for example.
For this reason I use `Math.floor(scrollTop)`. This seems a bit "hacky". Will I find cases where i should implement ceil instead of floor and the other way around? 
Is there a better solution? Maybe `Math.Round` ?

Comment: What about `Math.abs(scrollHeight - (scrollTop + clientHeight) <= 1`. Works fine for me so far.

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me a lot. Better solution than event listener!

Comment: This is actually not a good solution if you want to implement something like infinite scrolling. If you load more elements e.g. below, your scroll event will trigger again causing the `bottom` value to be `true` again. If you have something like an API call here: `if (bottom) { ... }`, it will be called twice.

Answer (score 47):

Here's a solution using React Hooks and ES6:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const List = () => {
  const listInnerRef = useRef();

  const onScroll = () => {
    if (listInnerRef.current) {
      const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = listInnerRef.current;
      const isNearBottom = scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight;

      if (isNearBottom) {
        console.log("Reached bottom");
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const listInnerElement = listInnerRef.current;

    if (listInnerElement) {
      listInnerElement.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

      // Clean-up
      return () => {
        listInnerElement.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="list">
      <div className="list-inner" ref={listInnerRef}>
        {/* List items */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Comment: And to do it without hooks you just have to call onScroll and use the event param like this: `if ((event.target.clientHeight + event.target.scrollTop) >= event.target.scrollHeight) {...`

Answer (score 21):

This answer belongs to Brendan, let's make it functional

```
export default () => {
   const handleScroll = (e) => {
       const bottom = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight;
       if (bottom) { 
           console.log("bottom")
       }
    }

  return (
     <div onScroll={handleScroll}  style={{overflowY: 'scroll', maxHeight: '400px'}}  >
        //overflowing elements here
   </div>
  )
}
```

If the first div is not scrollable it won't work and onScroll didn't work for me in a child element like div after the first div so onScroll should be at the first HTML tag that has an overflow

Comment: `===` not always work.
I used `e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop - e.target.clientHeight < 10`

Comment: this is by far the easiest solution

Answer (score 10):

We can also detect div's scroll end by using ref.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from 'style.scss';

class Gallery extends Component{ 

  paneDidMount = (node) => {    
    if(node) {      
      node.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll.bind(this));      
    }
  }

  handleScroll = (event) => {    
    var node = event.target;
    const bottom = node.scrollHeight - node.scrollTop === node.clientHeight;
    if (bottom) {      
      console.log("BOTTOM REACHED:",bottom); 
    }    
  }

  render() {
    var that = this;        
    return(<div className={styles.gallery}>
      <div ref={that.paneDidMount} className={styles.galleryContainer}>
        ...
      </div>

    </div>);   
  }
}

export default withRouter(Gallery);
```

Answer (score 7):

Extending chandresh's answer to use react hooks and ref I would do it like this;

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Scrollable() {
    const [referenceNode, setReferenceNode] = useState();
    const [listItems] = useState(Array.from(Array(30).keys(), (n) => n + 1));

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => referenceNode.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, []);

    function handleScroll(event) {
        var node = event.target;
        const bottom = node.scrollHeight - node.scrollTop === node.clientHeight;
        if (bottom) {
            console.log('BOTTOM REACHED:', bottom);
        }
    }

    const paneDidMount = (node) => {
        if (node) {
            node.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
            setReferenceNode(node);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div
            ref={paneDidMount}
            style={{overflowY: 'scroll', maxHeight: '400px'}}
        >
            <ul>
                {listItems.map((listItem) => <li>List Item {listItem}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think `referenceNoce` should be defined by `useRef` instead of `useState`, right?

Answer (score 6):

Add following functions in your React.Component and you're done :]

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll, false);
  }

  onScroll = () => {
    if (this.hasReachedBottom()) {
      this.props.onScrollToBottom();
    }
  };

  hasReachedBottom() {
    return (
      document.body.offsetHeight + document.body.scrollTop ===
      document.body.scrollHeight
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered but, I think another good solution is to use what's already available out in the open source community instead of DIY. [React Waypoints](https://github.com/civiccc/react-waypoint) is a library that exists to solve this very problem. (Though don't ask me why the this problem space of determining if a person scrolls past an HTML element is called "waypoints," haha)

I think it's very well designed with its props contract and definitely encourage you to check it out.

Answer (score 4):

The solution below works fine on most of browsers but has problem with some of them.

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

The better and most accurate is to use the code below which works on all browsers.

```
Math.abs(e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight - e.target.scrollTop) < 1
```

So the final code should be something like this

```
const App = () => {
   const handleScroll = (e) => {
     const bottom = Math.abs(e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight - e.target.scrollTop) < 1;
     if (bottom) { ... }
   }
   return(
     <div onScroll={handleScroll}>
       ...
     </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a div with 0 height after your scrolling div. then use [this custom hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008608/12893044) to detect if this div is visible.

```
  const bottomRef = useRef();
  const reachedBottom = useCustomHooks(bottomRef);

  return(
  <div>
   {search resault}
  </div>
  <div ref={bottomRef}/> )
```

`reachedBottom`  will toggle to `true` if you reach bottom

Answer (score 1):

I used follow in my code

```
.modify-table-wrap {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And add code in target js

```
    handleScroll = (event) => {
        const { limit, offset } = this.state
        const target = event.target
        if (target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop === target.clientHeight) {
            this.setState({ offset: offset + limit }, this.fetchAPI)
        }
    }
    return (
            <div className="modify-table-wrap" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
               ...
            <div>
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate whether my browser has scrolled to the bottom of a div, I settled with this solution:

```
const el = document.querySelector('.your-element');
const atBottom = Math.ceil(el.scrollTop + el.offsetHeight) === el.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Custom hook to know if the scroll is complete

**Usecase**:  `useIsScrollComplete` hook returns a variable `isScrollComplete` which is a boolean with an initial value of `false` and set to `true` if the scroll is complete.

> Note: The below snippet is not runnable. Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/anjantalatam/custom-react-hooks?file=src%2FApp.tsx) for runnable code.

```js
function useIsScrollComplete<TElement extends HTMLElement | null>({
  ref,
  querySelector,
  markAsComplete = true,
}: IUseIsScrollComplete<TElement>) {
  const [isScrollComplete, setIsScrollComplete] = useState(false);

  const onScroll: EventListener = useCallback(({ target }) => {
    const { scrollHeight, clientHeight, scrollTop } = target as Element;

    if (Math.abs(scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollTop) < THRESHOLD) {
      setIsScrollComplete(true);
    } else {
      setIsScrollComplete(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    const targetElement = querySelector
      ? element?.querySelector(querySelector)
      : element;

    if (targetElement) {
      const { scrollHeight, clientHeight } = targetElement;

      if (scrollHeight === clientHeight) {
        // set scroll is complete if there is no scroll
        setIsScrollComplete(true);
      }

      targetElement.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

      if (isScrollComplete && markAsComplete) {
        targetElement.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      }

      return () => {
        targetElement.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      };
    }
  }, [isScrollComplete, markAsComplete, onScroll, querySelector, ref]);

  return { isScrollComplete };
}
```

Usage:

```
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const { isScrollComplete } = useIsScrollComplete({ ref: divRef });

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={divRef}>
           <p>Scrollable Content</p>
      </div>

      {isScrollComplete && (
        <p>Scroll is Complete ✅</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Other use-cases:

1. You can use `querySelector` to target a child of an element that you don't have direct access to.
2. `markAsComplete` prop -> specifies whether to mark the scroll as complete. Defaults to `true`. If set to `false`, the scroll is observed even after the scroll is complete. i.e if you move back from the bottom to the top, `isScrollComplete` will be `false`. ( Ex: When you want to show pagination of the table only when the scroll is at the bottom of the table and should hide when the scroll is anywhere else )
3. If the container does not have scroll, the value is set to `true` by default.

---

Open Code in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/anjantalatam/custom-react-hooks?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

PS: The custom hook is maintained and updated [here](https://github.com/anjantalatam/custom-react-hooks) for more use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This answer belongs to Brendan, but I am able to use that code in this way.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
        const bottom =
            e.target.scrollingElement.scrollHeight -
                e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop ===
            e.target.scrollingElement.clientHeight;
        console.log(e);
        console.log(bottom);
        if (bottom) {
            console.log("Reached bottom");
        }
    });
```

> While others are able to access directly inside target by
> `e.target.scrollHeight`, 
>  I am able to achieve same by
> `e.target.scrollingElement.scrollHeight`

Answer (score 0):

I made this example for chat in my project it works

This function uses the scrollHeight and clientHeight properties of
the container element to calculate the difference and set the
scrollTop property accordingly.

```
  import  { useEffect } from "react";
  const chatContainerRef = useRef(null);

  function scrollToBottom() {
      if (chatContainerRef.current) {
       const { scrollHeight, clientHeight } = chatContainerRef.current;
       chatContainerRef.current.scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight;
      }
   }

  function Chat(props) {
      const { messages } = props;

      useEffect(() => {
       scrollToBottom();
      }, [messages]);

    return (
      <div className="chat-container" ref={chatContainerRef}>
      {/* render chat messages here */}
      </div>
    );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without js, I achieved the enforcement to scroll to bottom by including the event element (e.g button) inside the ScrollView, see example below.

```
<View style={styles.rootContainer}>
    <ScrollView 
        style={{paddingTop: 16, paddingBottom: 16}} 
        adding persistentScrollbar={true} 
    >
        <Text>
            ..... multipage paragraphs....
        </Text>        
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <PrimaryButton onPress={props.Submit}>Submit</PrimaryButton>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: This answer has no relation to the question, and is not very useful