# How to detect page scroll to top in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a UI problem to solve in React. When the user start scroll, will add a background class to the header. When scrolling to the top of the page, header background disappear.

I have figure out how to add the background while scrolling and modify the state, but how to detect whenever user scroll to the top of the page?

Comment: Check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585542/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-react-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585542/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-react-js)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it by adding a listener `window.onscroll` and watch in this listener for `window.pageYOffset`. Here is the example https://codepen.io/teimurjan/pen/NzMgKz?#.

Comment: @Dr.Dean no problems :)

Comment: how to implement that with useEffect()?

Answer (score 4):

```
const handleScroll = (e: React.UIEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    if(e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
       alert("on top")
    }
}
```

```html
<div onScroll={handleScroll}>
       
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another version using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [Functional Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

```js
const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.onscroll = () =>
      window.pageYOffset === 0 && console.log("back at top");

    return () => (window.onscroll = null);
  });

  return <div className="container">I'm a very large box</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What about use the same functionality in a child div which has a limited height with scrollY?