# Get scroll position with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use reactjs and want to handle scroll with `click` event.

Firstly, I rendered list of posts with `componentDidMount`.

Secondly, by `click event` on each post in list, It will display post detail and scroll to top (because I put post detail to top position of page).

Thirdly, by clicking `"close button"` in post detail, it will return previous list of posts but I want website will scroll to exactly to position of clicked post.

I use like this:

Click event to view post detail:

```
inSingle = (post, e) => {
   this.setState({
        post: post,
        theposition: //How to get it here?
   });
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

I want to get state of `theposition` then I can do scroll exactly to position of clicked post by `'Close event'`.

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: @SungKim I am using the latest version

Comment: Related, vanilla-JS canonical: [Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom (not just the window, but any element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-not-just-the-window-but-any-element)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should work:

```
this.setState({
  post: post,
  theposition: window.pageYOffset
});
```

EDIT: To update the vertical position every time you scroll, you could utilize `event listeners` like this (also suggested by Lucas Andrade in a separate answer):

```
const [scrollYPosition, setScrollYPosition] = React.useState(0);

const handleScroll = () => {
    const newScrollYPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    setScrollYPosition(newScrollYPosition);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);

// Now the vertical position is available with `scrollYPosition`
console.log(scrollYPosition)
```

And here's a bit of trivia:

`window.pageYOffset` is an alias of `window.scrollY` property which returns the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled
vertically from the origin, i.e. Y coordinate of the top edge of the current viewport. If the document is not scrolled at all up or down, then `scrollY` is 0.

Similarly, you can get the number of pixels the document is scrolled horizontally from the origin using `scrollX` property (`window.pageXOffset` alias).

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

Comment: it is bad no ? I mean if you setState, you reRender your component each time, seems to be better to combine useState and useEffect or useLayoutEffect

Comment: https://github.com/n8tb1t/use-scroll-position 
use-scroll-position solves this by using throttling technic to avoid too many reflows (the browser to recalculate everything).

Answer (score 85):

In case you need to keep on track of the scroll position, you can use react hooks to do so, that way it's possible to check the scroll position any time you need it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

...
// inside component:

const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setScrollPosition(position);
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);
```

In this case `useEffect` will behavior similar to `componentDidMount`, it will fire once the component has rendered, but also in every render, as Jared Beach commented bellow: "window.addEventListener is smart enough to discard subsequent calls with the same parameters". . Make sure to return the cleanup function, similar to what you'd do in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Appreciate the solution. However, saying `useEffect` is similar to `componentDidMount` is a little misleading. It runs every single render, not just the first. This code works still because window.addEventListener is smart enough to discard subsequent calls with the same parameters

Comment: Always giving window.pageYOffset 0

Comment: He has the second argument to useEffect being an empty array, which is the similar to componentDidMount.  If that wasn't there, it would be similar to componentDidUpdate.

Comment: In my solution I added [scrollPosition] as an argument, so it will only change if the state changes. Are there any pros or Cons? I'm relatively new to react.

Answer (score 55):

You can use event listener in react like you will use in other js framework or library.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll)
}

listenToScroll = () => {
  const winScroll =
    document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop

  const height =
    document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
    document.documentElement.clientHeight

  const scrolled = winScroll / height

  this.setState({
    theposition: scrolled,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function useWindowPosition() {
  const [scrollPosition, setPosition] = useState(0);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function updatePosition() {
      setPosition(window.pageYOffset);
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
    updatePosition();
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
  }, []);
  return scrollPosition;
}
```

Comment: what's the point of using `useLayoutEffect` here ?

Comment: Depends on what will you do with the scroll position, but generally, if you want to perform some DOM measurements (like getting scroll coordinates) it might be better to useLayoutEffect since it runs after DOM mutations have been performed but BEFORE the node gets painted on the screen. Hence if you will further mutate the DOM using that data, you will avoid stuff like screen flickering

Answer (score 9):

Combining some of the other answers, this is exactly what is needed here. Simply use this hook to get the scrollX (horizontal) and scrollY (vertical) positions from the window. It'll be updated as the user scrolls.

```
/// in useWindowScrollPositions.js

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useWindowScrollPositions = () => {

   const [scrollPosition, setPosition] = useState({ scrollX: 0, scrollY: 0 })

   useEffect(() => {
    function updatePosition() {
        setPosition({ scrollX: window.scrollX, scrollY: window.scrollY })
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)
    updatePosition()

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)
   }, [])

   return scrollPosition
}
```

Then call the hook in your function component:

```
/// in MyComponent.jsx

import { useWindowScrollPositions } from 'path/to/useWindowScrollPositions'

export const MyComponent = () => {
   const { scrollX, scrollY } = useWindowScrollPositions()
   
   return <div>Scroll position is ({scrollX}, {scrollY})</div>
}
```

> Note that `window.pageXOffset` and `window.pageYOffset`, which were used in the other answers from years ago, have been deprecated in favor of `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the native react event listener.

```
<div onScroll={(e) => console.log("scrolling!", e.target.scrollTop)}>
    <h3>Some huge div</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
theposition: e.y // or, e.pageY
```

Or,

```
theposition: e.clientY - e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Answer (score 3):

to get current scroll position you can use

horizontal scrolling amount  **window.pageXOffset**

vertical scrolling amount  **window.pageYOffset**

Answer (score 1):

Found this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled):

```
element.scrollHeight - Math.abs(element.scrollTop) === element.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

this repo helped me a lot  https://github.com/n8tb1t/use-scroll-position

```
yarn add @n8tb1t/use-scroll-position

import { useScrollPosition } from '@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position'


useScrollPosition(({ prevPos, currPos }) => {
 console.log(currPos.x)
 console.log(currPos.y)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.scrollY instead of window.pageYOffset(deprecated).

```
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      
      const handleScroll = () => {
        const position = window.scrollY;
        setScrollPosition(position);
      }

      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
   
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a npm package to track the user scroll position
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-collections

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34301413)