# Trigger Animation by scrolling to a predefined Component/Node

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, ref, dom-node

I would like to be able to "bind" the `useScrollTrigger` hook to a specific `Component`/`Node` rather than the `window` default value.

The following shows the `useScrollTrigger` expected parameters:

```
export interface UseScrollTriggerOptions {
  disableHysteresis?: boolean;
  target?: Node | Window;
  threshold?: number;
}
```

I tried to pass a reference to my Component but this has caused a crash. The Material-UI library does not explain how to use `useScrollTrigger` for things other than interactions with an `AppBar`.

The following code snippets illustrates what I would like to achieve:

```
const ref = React.useRef();
const scrollTrigger = useScrollTrigger({
  disableHysteresis: true,
  target: ref.current,
});

<Grid container spacing={2}>
  {services.map((service) => (
    <Grid key={uid(service)} item md={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
      <Grow
        mountOnEnter
        in={scrollTrigger}
        timeout={2048}
      >
        <Card
          ref={ref}
          className={classes.card}
          elevation={2}
        >
          <CardHeader --- REDACTED ---/>
          <CardContent --- REDACTED --->
            --- REDACTED ---
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions --- REDACTED --->
            --- REDACTED ---
        </Card>
      </Grow>
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have known the solution.

Based on these discussions https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/20184 https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32477, the `useScrollTrigger` hook is not designed to listen to whether the component/node is scrolled or not.

It's designed to listen to whether the `windows` is scrolled or not.

Perhaps you could create a custom hook to detect whether the component/node is scrolled or not by following this discussion [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585542/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-react-js).