# How do I detect if an element scrolls off the viewport using React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

[Sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH1ty.png)

I want to add a custom gradient style when the element is no longer visible inside the viewport. By default, the buttons are solid colors but when scrolled to the left outside the viewport, the edge should have a gradient such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH1ty.png).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514676/react-check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514676/react-check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom)

Comment: Is it not easier to overlay the edges of the viewport with a transparent-to-white gradient?

Comment: Use Intersection Observer API to Detect if Element is in Viewport, details here – https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-detect-if-element-is-in-viewport-intersection-observer-api/