# how to check if an html form has been rendered on the page using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to check if an html element(form) has been rendered?

```
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Using React and Nextjs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514676/react-check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom

Comment: That thread works for reactjs though. I'm looking for nextjs compatible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check it using `window` object.

Just check it like a vanilla javascript using `window.document.getElementBy...`.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for a less hacky solution; preferably for nextjs.